# VB6 Setup Fails To Install-Missing Dependencies

Tags: vb6

I have a legacy VB6 software that I have recently compiled to install on several client computer. The issues is however, whenever I attempt install, various errors arise including:

***Component 'MSHFLXGD.OCX' failed to register***

***The program cant start because CRPE32.dll is missing from your computer***

How can i ensure that the setup package is complete with all the necessary files and dependencies it needs?

Comment: `CRPE32.dll` is a crystal reports component

Comment: Ok..that error showed up on a computer that does not have crystal installed. MSHFLXGD.OCX' appeared on another that does have crystal reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [Support Statement for VB6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708)

Supported Runtime Files to Distribute with Your Application

comct232.ocx
...
....

**mshflxgd.ocx**

**Unsupported Runtime Files**: Some files have either fallen out of mainstream support or they were never included as a part of the runtime redist (e.g. they were included in \Tools folder on the IDE media to support legacy VB4/VB5 applications or they were **3rd party controls**). These files are not supported on Windows; instead they are subject to whatever support agreement applies to the media they were shipped with. These files have been tested to work on Vista as part of our application compatibility and testing process, but this implies no warranties around support and servicing. In some instances, later versions of these libraries are supported. Details on backward compatibility or migration to supported versions are provided below.

---

My comment: so I guess (if I understood the documentation correctly) you may need to ship **mshflxgd.ocx** with your app. Also thanks to Plutonix, for pointing out Crystal Reports dll: CRPE32.dll, which might belong to the category mentioned above: **3rd party controls**.